# Implementing file reading and Classes with arrays

Tags: java, arrays, file, filereader

I'm here today because I need help with some code for my intro to Java course that I'm in right now.

Basically I have to read a .txt file and set each line in the `.txt` file to a new Class object called `Student` which simply has a name and a score for a quiz or test or whatever. Basically the `.txt` file is as follows:

```
James 78
Jerry 90
Henry 95
Juice 63
Alex 88
Nick 83
```

I know how to read the file but don't know how to go about creating a new student for each line within the text file. Once that's completed I have to use the Getters and Setters within my `Student` class to get the score values of each student and put them into an array so I can implement the array into my `Lab7` Method that Bubble sorts the array.

My code is as follows:

My `Student` Class:

```
public class Student {
    private String name;
    private int score;

    public Student(String name, int score){
        this.name = name;
        this.score = score;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getScore() {
        return score;
    }

    public void setScore(int score) {
        this.score = score;
    }

}
```

And my main which is where I need the help:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Lab7 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    //fileName differs per location of the file
    String fileName = "/Users/Gerard/Desktop/scores.txt";

    String line = null;

    try {
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(fileName);

        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
            System.out.println(line);
        }   
        bufferedReader.close();         
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
        System.out.println("Unable to open file '" + fileName + "'");                
    }
    catch(IOException ex){
        System.out.println("Error reading file '" + fileName + "'");                  

    }
}

//Code that Gets Value of scores using getters and setters from student class 
//and stores them into an array to be used for Lab7 which bubble sorts the array.


public int[] Lab7(int[] arr){
    int val;
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length-1;i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < arr.length-1;j++){
            if(arr[j-i] > arr[j]){
                val = arr[j-1];
                arr[j-1] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = val;   
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Run "+ (i+1) + Arrays.toString(arr));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your Lab7 method is taking int[] as parameter. You can create a array of scores  and add score in that array in while loop where you are reading your file. Then you can pass that array to sorting method. Not sure why you want to create Student object.

Comment: idk why either. It's just what my teacher says to do :(

Answer (score 0):

So all that you need to do is create a new object of type `Student` each time you read a line then put in into a postion in the array. Something like

```
Student s = new Student();
Student[] sArray = new Student[5];
sArray[0] = s;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code. It will give you student objects in student array. You can use values in student object to pass to sorting method.

Do handling for null pointer and ArrayIndexOutOfBound Exceptions.

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
//fileName differs per location of the file
String fileName = "/Users/Gerard/Desktop/scores.txt";

String line = null;

try {
    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(fileName);

    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

    Student[] studentArr = new Student[6];

    int counter = 0;

    while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
        System.out.println(line);
        String[] arr = line.split(" ");
        Student student = new Student(arr[0], Integer.parseInt(arr[1]));

        studentArr[counter] = student;
        counter++;

    }
    bufferedReader.close();
}
catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
    System.out.println("Unable to open file '" + fileName + "'");
}
catch(IOException ex){
    System.out.println("Error reading file '" + fileName + "'");

}
```

}